# Add Another Workflow Manager Server to Farm

Tags: workflow-manager

I'm struggling to find good information so wondering if anyone has any input.  Looks like my only standalone Workflow Manager server has choked up a bit with one site in particular, but seems to be fine with others.  Lots went on there with restoring lists/workflows/etc.

Anyways, it sounded like removing the server from the farm or recreating the WF farm or perhaps adding another to the farm and then removing the problem server could do it too.  My question is if I tried the latter as a least intrusive option, do all the components need to be at the same level as the other WF server? I believe the original server is on CU2 maybe and I'd like to get the new server current.

Answer (score 1):

Recreating the farm is safe since all data is held in the WFM/SB databases, but I would consider updating to Azure Service Bus 1.1 + WFM CU5 and WFM Client CU4. Only after upgrading and continuing to find issues would I consider ejecting the server and building a replacement.

Comment: My original thought was to migrate to a new OS > Windows 2008 R2, but certainly that adds a bit more complexity to it all.  But I can just reuse the existing server initially.  Do you have good references for doing an upgrade from 1.0 CU2?  I had put together some documentation for my Dev upgrade and it didn't like the reuse of the existing DBs for some reason, and then just created fresh DBs.

Comment: I've done upgrades from CU2 and haven't specifically had any issues like what you faced. Just make sure you use Azure SB 1.1 and WFM CU5 via WebPI.

Comment: So you'd say remove from the farm, upgrade the components and then add back to the farm?  Or upgrade the components, remove from the farm and then add back?  Or doesn't matter?  Appreciate the help!